# Get all ids in a database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to get all the ids in a database from all columns that have an ID field.
My script so far is:

```
BEGIN
FOR tname IN (select table_name from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'ID' and owner='PACC_USER') LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
   'select unique id from ' || tname;
END LOOP;
End;
```

I get the error `PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '||'`. What is the problem exactly? Any help is welcomed :)

Comment: `tname` is a record. You need `tname.table_name`. Your next problem will be what to do with the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `tname` is a record for referencing the cursor result set i.e. a namespace not an attribute. Fix it like this:

```
BEGIN
    FOR tname IN (select table_name 
                   from all_tab_columns 
                   where column_name = 'ID' and owner='PACC_USER') 
    LOOP
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
       'select unique id from ' || tname.table_name ;
    END LOOP;
End;
```

One would hope that a column called ID would return unique rows without needing the `unique` keyword but we live in troubled times.

Your code needs to select results into something: PL/SQL is not T-SQL, it requires target variables. So let's improve your code a bit more.

```
declare 
    ids_nt sys.dbms-debug_vc2coll;
BEGIN
    FOR tname IN (select table_name 
                   from all_tab_columns 
                   where column_name = 'ID' and owner='PACC_USER') 
    LOOP
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
           'select unique id from ' || tname.table_name
           bulk collect into ids_nt;
       dbms_output.put_line('IDS for table '|| tname.table_name);
       for idx in ids_nt.first() .. ids_nt.last loop
           dbms_output.put_line(ids_nt(idx));
       end loop;
    END LOOP;
End;
```

Maybe this isn't the kind of thing you want to do with the IDs. If so please edit your question to clarify your intent.

Answer (score -2):

> Select column_name,table name from all_tab_column where upper(column_name)=upper('Id') ;